# High MySQL CPU usage but no heavy query

Tags: mysql, linux, cpu-usage

When I run "top" command on my Linux it shows that MySQL is taking 400%-500% CPU usage. But when I run 'watch mysqladmin pr" command to see a list of queries being run by MySQL then it shows just 2, 3 queries and that too only taking 2, 3 seconds.
The "top" command shows MySQL constantly fluctuating CPU usage like 130%, 200%, 340%, 230%, 400%, 440%, 635%, 335% e.t.c. but "watch mysqladmin pr" command is not showing queries that are taking up CPU usage. How do I check why MySQL is using so much CPU?

Thanks

Comment: Not a programming question, try http://www.serverfault.com http://dba.stackexchange.com . That aside, is it waiting on disk IO perhaps?

Comment: Ok may be mods can move this to appropriate forum!? Regarding IO how do I check it or is there a way to optimize it I mean do I need to increase some kind of buffer size?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a huge transaction being rolled back? This will show 100% cpu but no active queries. Restarting mysql won't help as the rollback continues after a restart [source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-transaction-management.html): second section on huge transactions)

If you run `show engine innodb status` (assuming you're running innodb) there is information under the TRANSACTION heading - something along the lines of:

`---TRANSACTION 7AB09, ACTIVE 3601 sec rollback
ROLLING BACK 48157 lock struct(s), heap size 5585336, 2856641 row lock(s), undo log entries 4921485 
MySQL thread id 53, OS thread handle 0x7f3d503ab700, query id 4937822 localhost 127.0.0.1 user`